# Not receiving UIKeyboardWillShowNotification after changing UIWindow.rootViewController

Tags: ios, nsnotificationcenter, uiwindow

I no longer am receiving observer notifications for UIKeyboardWillShowNotification events after changing my UIWindow RootViewController to a new view controller I instantiated from storyboard.

Please reply only when you know what the problem is and if you happen to know how to fix it.

THANKS!

Okay it's really simple and I don't know if this counts as more information or not but here it goes.

1. In my AppDelegate I am changing the rootViewController of the window in the appDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions like so:

`self.window?.rootViewController = newViewController`

2. In the newViewController I have a UITextField and the following code does not work unless i remove the above rootViewController changing code and make the newViewController as the initial View Controller from the storyboard. The notification observer code is as follows:

`NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserverForName(UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()) {[unowned self] (note) -> Void in
            printf("done")
        }`

It appears as if the event are no longer delivered to the new view controller once i change the window rootViewController.

Comment: Hm can you post some more information? Are you calling   `NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "keyboardWillShow:", name: UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)`in your new View Controller?

Comment: @SunburstEnzo are you able to identify the problem with my code now?

Comment: Does the code that I wrote work?